# Install local package through a Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, virtualenv

I have started learning Docker and I have developed a Python package (not published anywhere, it is just used internally) that installs and works fine locally (here I will call it `mypackage`). However, when trying to install it in a Docker container, Python in the container fails to recognise it even though during the build of the image no error was raised. The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# install Ubuntu 20.04
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# update Ubuntu packages
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt update
RUN apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install -y apt-utils \ 
           build-essential \
           curl \
           mysql-server \ 
           libmysqlclient-dev \ 
           libffi-dev \ 
           libssl-dev \ 
               libxml2-dev \ 
               libxslt1-dev \ 
               unzip \
               zlib1g-dev

# install Python 3.9
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common gcc && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.9 python3.9-dev python3.9-distutils python3-pip python3-apt python3.9-venv
 
# make symlink (overriding default Python3.8 installed with Ubuntu)
RUN rm /usr/bin/python3
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3

# copy package files and source code
RUN mkdir mypackage
COPY pyproject.toml setup.cfg setup.py requirements.txt ./mypackage/
COPY src mypackage/src/

# add path
ENV PACKAGE_PATH=/mypackage/
ENV PATH="$PACKAGE_PATH/:$PATH" 

# install mypackage
RUN pip3 install -e ./mypackage

CMD ["python3.9", "main.py"]
```

So the above runs successfully, but if I run `sudo docker run -it test_image bin/bash` and run `pip3 list`, the package will not be there and a `ModuleNotFoundError` when running code depending on `mypackage`. Interestingly if I create a virtual environment by replacing this:

```
ENV PACKAGE_PATH=/mypackage/
ENV PATH="$PACKAGE_PATH/:$PATH"
```

by this:

```
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3.9 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
```

it works. Ideally, I want to know why I need to create a virtual environment and how can I run local packages in a container without creating virtual environments.

Comment: The Dockerfile mentions that you have two different Python runtimes installed in your image; are you getting the Python 3.8 Pip, rather than the Python 3.9 one?  (Would it be easier to use the `python:3.9` image than to try to recreate it?)

Comment: @DavidMaze the pip3 being used is form Python 3.9 (that one was also hard to set up). I thought about using a python image but I read that I can use only one in a dockerfile and I really need the Ubuntu image (I hope I have understood you suggestion correctly).

Comment: The standard [Docker Hub `python` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) is built on Debian, which should be close enough to Ubuntu for most practical purposes.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am not sure if I am fully understanding what you mentioned about the python image. Do you mean that image is built on top of an Ubuntu image and, therefore, I could run "sudo docker run -it test_image bin/bash" and I would be in a Ubuntu/Debian environment? I am asking because I need to do other stuff in the dockerfile (like managing files, use aws configure, etc...).

Comment: I would not delete `/usr/bin/python3` and replace it with my own like you do. I would be worried that it might break things. -- Anyway, use the full paths instead of unreliable shortcuts like `pip3`. For example: `path/to/python -m pip list`, this will be much more reliable: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ -- You should not need shortcuts in a file, shortcuts are only useful when working on the command line during interactive session.